# Android-Permission Settings and SharedPreferences Issue

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-sharedpreferences

I am developing an application and i am saving every form data to SharedPreferences. It works fine,but when i destroy my app i back to app the form data still exists.Cause my app need **permission at runtime**

I try to :

- Fill my First Form
- Go to my Second Form and Fill it
- Back to First Form (cause runtime permission exists in here, when next button clicked)
- Open Settings
- Disable Permission
- Open my App
- My Second Form data loss

I try another case, like destroy app. Open another app, my form still exists. Just in **Settings -> App -> Permission and Disable permission**.

> Is Android do some check or anything activities that make my
>   preferences loss?

I create my Prefs util like this :

```
/**
     * Initialize the Prefs helper class to keep a reference to the SharedPreference for this
     * application the SharedPreference will use the package provinceName of the application as the Key.
     *
     * @param context the Application context.
     */
    public static void initPrefs(Context context) {
        if (mPrefs == null) {
            String key = context.getPackageName();
            if (key == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Prefs key may not be null");
            }
            mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide some code. Where do you store and load the values into the form(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find how it works and see some examples:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Alternatively, if you need just one shared preference file for your activity, you can use the getPreferences() method:
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);